# Purpose of .dir, .install files in packages

Tags: installation, packaging

When packaging Ubuntu packages, there's always these funny .dir and .install files around. I suppose their purpose is to somehow indicate what files are to be installed, but I'm not so sure about what the the format of those files is, nor what the consequences are when they are omitted.

Comment: If you're trying to package a binary program as .deb, use the provided tools, make a proper debian "source" package -- in this case, you're providing already-compiled binary files, you may use `dh_make` and edit the file `debian/install` to point your files to the appropriate folder. Personally, I've never seen, nor tampered with ".install" or ".dir" files/folders.

Comment: Well it seems that if I totally remove all of those files, nothing is installed at all although the libraries and headers are to be found in pretty much standard folders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`debian/install` and `debian/packagename.install` files both have the same purpose, the latter being used in case you build multiple binary packages from the same source (so you need to distinguish which files go into which resulting package).

If the source `Makefile` (and other install system) already takes care of installing for you, they are generally not needed, (extra) files that aren't installed otherwise can be installed by these.

The syntax is simply:

```
path/sourcedir/file path/installdir
# for example
data/foo.jpg usr/share/packagename
```

See http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install

--

Likewise goes for `debian/dirs` and `debian/packagename.dirs` which instead creates empty directories:

```
path/installdir
```

It's normally unnecessary unless you specifically need an empty directory or if there is a problem with the source `Makefile`...

See http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#dirs